# VBA - How to tag duplicate data based on given criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Good Day!, I'm still new in VBA any help would be appreciated. :)

My problem is, I'm doing a generated report in VBA now I'm in the part where i need to get the the same data in a specific column and add another column to the last to tag it based on given criteria..

This are the criteria:

1. At least one "same data" per month(up to 3 months)
2. "same data"  within 15 days from installed date
3. More than 3 "same data" within 30 days
4. 2 or more "change modem" within 30 days

note: same data is in column(Service number) and also for criteria no.4

For example:

```
Completed-date | Installed-date  | Service# | Status       | Tag |
03/03/2016     | 03/03/2016      | 1111     | repaired     |     |
04/04/2016     | 04/04/2016      | 1111     | defective    |     |
05/05/2016     | 05/06/2016      | 1111     | defective    |     |
06/06/2016     | 06/07/2016      | 2222     | repaired     |     |
07/07/2016     | 07/07/2016      | 3333     | defective    |     |
08/08/2016     | 08/08/2016      | 4444     | change modem |     |
08/09/2016     | 08/09/2016      | 4444     | change modem |     |
```

Column Tag is still empty coz we havent chose a criteria,
now the sample output is like this..

Output:

```
Completed-date | Installed-date  | Service# | Status       | Tag |
03/03/2016     | 03/03/2016      | 1111     | repaired     |     |
04/04/2016     | 04/04/2016      | 1111     | defective    |     |
05/05/2016     | 05/06/2016      | 1111     | defective    |  1  |
06/06/2016     | 06/07/2016      | 2222     | repaired     |     |
07/07/2016     | 07/07/2016      | 3333     | defective    |     |
08/08/2016     | 08/08/2016      | 4444     | change modem |     |
08/09/2016     | 08/09/2016      | 4444     | change modem |  4  |
```

Now, as you can see in the Tag(column) we selected it base on criteria and
I only tag one data per duplicate base on the latest completed date.

1. At least one "same data(servicenumber)" per month(up to 3 months)
2. "same data"  within 15 days from installed date
3. More than 3 "same data(servicenumber)" within 30 days
4. 2 or more "change modem" within 30 days

Here's my code, my code only determines  the duplicate in row i don't know how to start to code the criteria.. please help me!...

```
Public Sub sample1()

Dim varCOMDate As Variant
Dim varServiceID As Variant
Dim varInstallationDate As Variant
Dim serviceIDRng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long

Set Sheet1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Sheets(1)
lngLastRow = Sheet1.Range("A" & wksht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set serviceIDRng = wksht.Range("C1:C" & lngLastRow)


 For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
   If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
   matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)

   If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
     Cells(iCntr, 2) = "Duplicate" (I want to start the loop of dates here)

   End If
  End If
 Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: It is unclear to me how your criteria system works, in that I can't see why something is being tagged or why it gets the tags that you've given. Can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, thank your for answer my question and sorry for my confusing question, The tag number is base on on this criteria.
1. At least one "same data(servicenumber)" per month(up to 3 months)
2. "same data" within 15 days from installed date
3. More than 3 "same data(servicenumber)" within 30 days
4. 2 or more "change modem" within 30 days

at tagged it 1  and 4 for because it falls in that criteria

Comment: Yes, you stated those criteria in your question, but I don't understand what you mean by them, especially in reference to how you have asserted tags `1` and `4` in your example output. Why is the line with the tag `4` tagged that way? There's only 2 entries in the entire table that has a `Service#` of `4444` - so where does the 4 come from?

Comment: Is the list labeled 1 through 4 the tags you use? I assumed it was a list of criteria that all had to be satisfied.

Comment: let's say, in the sample below there is service number 1111 that repeat for 3x but date is one month apart, this sample will fall in the criteria 1 which is 1. At least one "same data(servicenumber)" per month(up to 3 months)
because the service number repeat in 3months

Comment: yes it was, but i need to tag it based on those numbers

Comment: What is the expected behavior if there are 4 lines that repeat with "same data", but are more than 3 months apart?

Comment: None, but it needs to loop through all the criteria if it didnt fall just blank..

Comment: I hope someone can help me..

Comment: I don't have time to write up an example, but the pseudo-code is easy: forget `MATCH`, you should iterate over the `Service#` column and do a `SELECT` to create paths for each possible input. You'll need at least 2 variables for each possible input - keep track of the first occurrence and the "current" occurrence for comparison. On each iteration, evaluate if the criteria have expired or if they're being satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a snippet to help you off. It's not complete, and it barely accounts for outlier data. You have also not specified the criteria sufficiently, for example what is supposed to happen if there are several rows that fulfill the criteria, for example 5 occurrences of "1111" within a 3 month period.

You will have to change the code (or use it as inspiration to do something else) in accordance with what specific criteria you need.

```
Sub duplicateTaggerExample()
    Dim startRng As Range, currRng As Range
    Dim first1Var As Date, second1Var As Date, third1Var As Date

    Set startRng = Range("C2")
    Set currRng = startRng

    Do While (Not currRng Is Nothing And currRng.Value <> "")
        Select Case currRng.Value
            Case "1111"
                ' Test if we're beyond the criteria - if so, reset vars and skip
                If (CDate(currRng.Value) - firstVar) > 90 Then
                    first1Var = ""
                    second1Var = ""
                    third1Var = ""
                    GoTo SkipIteration
                End If

                ' If we haven't skipped the iteration, it means the criteria is still viable, so we need to proceed with the comparison
                If first1Var <> "" And second1Var <> "" Then
                    ' If both first and second vars are filled, we fill the third.
                    ' We can do this without further comparison, because we already checked if we're inside the window for the criteria or not.
                    third1Var = CDate(currRng.Value)
                ElseIf firstVar <> "" Then
                    ' If only the first var is filled, fill the 2nd var.
                    second1Var = CDate(currRng.Value)
                Else
                    ' Should never happen, but...
                    Debug.Print "Some error"
                End If

                ' If the third var is filled, criteria is matched and we need to mark the occurrence and reset vars
                If third1Var <> "" Then
                    currRng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "1"
                    first1Var = ""
                    second1Var = ""
                    third1Var = ""
                End If
            Case "2222"
                ' Fill these as well, but the criteria are different so you will have to use different code than the above
            Case "3333"

            Case "4444"

            Case Else
                ' something
        End Select
SkipIteration:
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Vegard i really appreciate your effort! :)
I'm really sorry i'm not really good in explanation...

Comment: I'm doing a generated report in VBA, and the content of this report are trouble tickets so now those tickets have lots of columns and data and my reference column is the service number. The reason the service number repeats is because the owner of the servicenumber=telephonenumber have complaints so a ticket will be created. The main purpose of this program is to repair those complaints based on the given criteria which is those 4.

Comment: I gathered as much, but what I mean is, you don't specify how the program should operate on your criteria. For example, many of the criteria have something like "at least X", but what about instance where there's more than the minimum number of X? What if there are 10 instances per month? Do we tag just the last occurrence, or all of them except the 2 first?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, the solution isn't complete - it's an example on how to start. There's no point in doing more work without knowing more about the criteria, re: my comment above. You should try to understand what my code is doing and see if you can come up with suggestions for how to make it work like you want.

Comment: I think approach the criteria incorrectly,
1. At least one ticket per month(up to 3 months) a ticket means trouble ticket for example my phone have a problem then i call the customer service the customer service will now create a trouble ticket and that ticket will be in the source file that i'm using. so basically if me for ex. have at least a ticket per month for the last 3month it will be tagged as 1. i hope its not confusing

Comment: 1 -  at least one ticket per month 
2 -  ticket within 15 days from installed date
3 -  more than 3 tickets within 30 days 
4 -  2 or more change modem within 30 days 

if there is 10 instances per month it will fall on no.3 and by instances do you mean tickets? sorry for my poor grammar please bare with me

Comment: For criteria number 1: What if there are 2 tickets the first month, no tickets the second month, and then 1 ticket the third month? That means there are 3 tickets over the past 3 months, but not 1 ticket each month. What do you want for this case? And what if there are 2 tickets per month? Which lines do you want tagged?

Comment: Ohhhh i seeeee, that example of you doesnt fall in any of the criteria right? In that case just leave it blank. And if there are 2 tickets there is another column which is completed date and it will based on the latest date

Comment: I don't know if it falls within the criteria or not - I am asking you if it does! I am asking you, what should the program do in these cases? You need to define your criteria more clearly - the explanation you have for them now *is not enough*, because you aren't explaining what to do for any other case than the bare minimum.

Comment: Your example doesnt fall in criteria 1 or in any other criteria so the output will be blank like in my sample output:

Comment: So if there is 1 report in January, 1 report in February, and 2 reports in March, this does not satisfy the criteria? But if it had been only 1 report in March, that would have satisfied the criteria?

Comment: Not in that case, if there is 1ticket in Jan, 1 ticket in feb, 2ticket in march it will satisfy the criteria because in criteria 1 its said that "at least one" so 2 or more will satisfy.

Comment: But lets say in jan,feb,march there are 2 tickets each in january ticket the dates are jan 20-21 in feb 1-2 in this case. It will fall in criteria 3 which is 3 tickets within 30 days

Comment: Im really grateful to you, Thank you for assisting me! :)

Comment: And what happens if multiple criteria are satisfied?

Comment: based it on completed date the latest one, hmmm this post is expanding so im going to post another one but for now im going to follow your advices, thank you for having me!

Answer (score 0):

@Vegard, I hope you don't mind me posting an answer after you, but I've been watching this post expand and I feel there's a lot in it for others to learn from.

@&A65726F, some of my answer may seem a bit, shall we say, robust, so by way of an olive branch I've posted some code below that will set you on your way for this problem.

Ok, so ...

1. I wonder if you have thought enough about the architecture of your project. The worksheet data, as it currently stands, will need a fair bit of validating and there is huge scope for input errors that could mess up your code. Relying, for example, on "change modem" to be correctly typed and correctly cased, and on the dates to be in the correct format and correctly ordered, is asking an awful lot. If the data is being imported from, say, a database, then is Excel VBA the most appropriate place to manipulate the data? If not, then your life would be much simpler if you could convert some of these fields to index values (eg "change modem" = 0, etc.) In my opinion, it would be a bold person who used this spreadsheet to inform the design of their company's customer servicing strategy.
2. Trying to use worksheet functions in your VBA for this task is going to make the code rather clumsy, especially if, as point 1, the data isn't reliable. If possible, read the data from the worksheet, run your appropriate algorithms within VBA and then write the results back to the sheet. My example below is by no means the most efficient, but, to give you an idea, I have read the data from the sheet and then grouped it by ServiceNumber within a `Collection`. If I were to spend any time on this task, I'd probably put it into subgroups of dates too.
3. Stackoverflow: it really does help if you can formulate your thoughts quite precisely before articulating your question. You can see from the string of 'to and fro' comments that there isn't enough information in your question. If this is the case then read people's comments carefully and go back and edit your question. Vegard has asked you a number of times to refine your criteria and yet you still have not done so. He's also asked you to go through his code and make sure you understand it, but you have just continued responding to him with no break. Everyone here wants to help and many are experts in their field; if they say they need additional information or something else needs to be done, then it really would be wise to heed their observations. Stackoverflow is not here to write your code for you, it is here to help guide you and overcome obstacles.

Below is some code that will begin attacking your problem. I have broken it into small, modular chunks so that you can see what each piece does and you can expand them as you go, for example there is a separate data validation routine. I do not intend to write your project for you, so please do spend some time going through it yourself. The idea is that you add to it yourself as you refine your criteria and expand your data validation. Paste this code into a `Module`:

```
Option Explicit
'Worksheet constants
Private Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
Private Const COMPLETED_DATE_COL As Long = 1
Private Const INSTALLED_DATE_COL As Long = 2
Private Const SERVICE_NUM_COL As Long = 3
Private Const STATUS_COL As Long = 4
Private Const TAG_COL As Long = 5
Private Const START_ROW As Long = 2

'Status constants
Private Const REPAIRED_ID As Integer = 0
Private Const DEFECTIVE_ID As Integer = 1
Private Const CHANGE_MODEM_ID As Integer = 2

'Tag test constants for variant array
Private Const T1_HIT_ID As Integer = 0
Private Const T2_HIT_ID As Integer = 1
Private Const T3_HIT_ID As Integer = 2
Private Const T4_HIT_ID As Integer = 3
Private Const ROW_ID As Integer = 4
Private Const COMPLETED_DATE_ID As Integer = 5
Private Const INSTALLED_DATE_ID As Integer = 6
Private Const SERVICE_COUNT_ID As Integer = 7
Private Const MODEM_COUNT_ID As Integer = 8

Private mStatusList As Collection

Public Sub RunMe()

    'Run this once
    Initialise

    Dim data As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    'Run each time you set the tags
    data = ReadData
    result = GetTagTests(data)
    WriteData result


End Sub

Private Sub Initialise()

    'Set the allowable list of status definitions
    Set mStatusList = New Collection
    mStatusList.Add REPAIRED_ID, "repaired"
    mStatusList.Add DEFECTIVE_ID, "defective"
    mStatusList.Add CHANGE_MODEM_ID, "change modem"

End Sub

Private Function ReadData() As Variant
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim data As Variant

    'Read the data to variant
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
        endRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, SERVICE_NUM_COL).End(xlUp).Row
        data = .Range(.Cells(START_ROW, COMPLETED_DATE_COL), .Cells(endRow, STATUS_COL)).Value2
    End With

    ReadData = data
End Function

Private Sub WriteData(data As Variant)

    'Size the range and pass in the array
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SHEET_NAME)
        .Cells(START_ROW, TAG_COL).Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).value = data
    End With
End Sub

Private Function GetTagTests(data As Variant) As Variant
    Dim serviceItems As Collection
    Dim rowData As Variant
    Dim tagResults() As Variant
    Dim tagTests As Variant
    Dim tagParams(0 To 8) As Variant
    Dim refDate As Date
    Dim r As Long

    'Dimension the output array
    ReDim tagResults(1 To UBound(data, 1), 1 To 1)

    'Loop through the data to assess for the tag criteria
    Set serviceItems = New Collection
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)

        'Validate the data
        rowData = ValidatedRow(data, r)

        If Not IsEmpty(rowData) Then

            'Acquire tag params for this service number
            tagTests = Empty
            On Error Resume Next
            tagTests = serviceItems(rowData(SERVICE_NUM_COL))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If IsEmpty(tagTests) Then 'it's a new service number
                tagParams(T1_HIT_ID) = False
                tagParams(T2_HIT_ID) = False
                tagParams(T3_HIT_ID) = False
                tagParams(T4_HIT_ID) = False
                tagParams(ROW_ID) = r
                tagParams(COMPLETED_DATE_ID) = rowData(COMPLETED_DATE_COL)
                tagParams(INSTALLED_DATE_ID) = rowData(INSTALLED_DATE_COL)
                tagParams(SERVICE_COUNT_ID) = 1
                tagParams(MODEM_COUNT_ID) = IIf(rowData(STATUS_COL) = CHANGE_MODEM_ID, 1, 0)
                serviceItems.Add tagParams, rowData(SERVICE_NUM_COL)
            Else

                'Run the first test
                refDate = DateAdd("m", 3, tagTests(COMPLETED_DATE_ID))
                If rowData(COMPLETED_DATE_COL) < refDate Then
                    tagTests(T1_HIT_ID) = True
                Else
                    If tagTests(T1_HIT_ID) Then
                        tagResults(tagTests(ROW_ID), 1) = 1
                    End If
                    tagTests(T1_HIT_ID) = False
                End If

                'Run the second test
                refDate = DateAdd("d", 15, tagTests(INSTALLED_DATE_ID))
                If rowData(COMPLETED_DATE_COL) < refDate Then
                    tagTests(T2_HIT_ID) = True
                Else
                    If tagTests(T2_HIT_ID) Then
                        tagResults(tagTests(ROW_ID), 1) = 2
                    End If
                    tagTests(T2_HIT_ID) = False
                End If

                'Run the third test
                refDate = DateAdd("d", 30, tagTests(COMPLETED_DATE_ID))
                If rowData(COMPLETED_DATE_COL) < refDate Then
                    If tagTests(SERVICE_COUNT_ID) >= 3 Then
                        tagTests(T3_HIT_ID) = True
                    Else
                        tagTests(T3_HIT_ID) = False
                    End If
                Else
                    tagTests(SERVICE_COUNT_ID) = 0
                End If

                'Run the fourth test
                If rowData(COMPLETED_DATE_COL) < refDate Then
                    If tagTests(MODEM_COUNT_ID) >= 1 Then
                        tagTests(T4_HIT_ID) = True
                    Else
                        tagTests(T4_HIT_ID) = False
                    End If
                Else
                    tagTests(MODEM_COUNT_ID) = 0
                End If

                'Update the values
                tagTests(COMPLETED_DATE_ID) = rowData(COMPLETED_DATE_COL)
                tagTests(ROW_ID) = r
                tagTests(INSTALLED_DATE_ID) = rowData(INSTALLED_DATE_COL)
                tagTests(SERVICE_COUNT_ID) = tagTests(SERVICE_COUNT_ID) + 1
                tagTests(MODEM_COUNT_ID) = tagTests(MODEM_COUNT_ID) + IIf(rowData(STATUS_COL) = CHANGE_MODEM_ID, 1, 0)

                'Update the collection with the new tag test params
                serviceItems.Remove rowData(SERVICE_NUM_COL)
                serviceItems.Add tagTests, rowData(SERVICE_NUM_COL)
            End If
        End If

    Next

    'Catch all the outstanding hits
    For Each tagTests In serviceItems

        If tagTests(T1_HIT_ID) Then
            tagResults(tagTests(ROW_ID), 1) = 1
        End If
        If tagTests(T2_HIT_ID) Then
            tagResults(tagTests(ROW_ID), 1) = 2
        End If
        If tagTests(T3_HIT_ID) Then
            tagResults(tagTests(ROW_ID), 1) = 3
        End If
        If tagTests(T4_HIT_ID) Then
            tagResults(tagTests(ROW_ID), 1) = 4
        End If

    Next

    GetTagTests = tagResults

End Function
Private Function ValidatedRow(data As Variant, r As Long) As Variant
    Dim d As Date
    Dim str As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim result(1 To 4) As Variant

    'Test each of the values for correct types
    On Error Resume Next
    d = CDate(data(r, COMPLETED_DATE_COL))
    result(COMPLETED_DATE_COL) = d

    d = CDate(data(r, INSTALLED_DATE_COL))
    result(INSTALLED_DATE_COL) = d

    str = CStr(data(r, SERVICE_NUM_COL))
    result(SERVICE_NUM_COL) = str

    i = mStatusList(CStr(data(r, STATUS_COL)))
    result(STATUS_COL) = i

    'But there's a lot more validating that ought to be done, eg
    'dates in sequence, completed before installed, etc.

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ValidatedRow = result
    Else
        ValidatedRow = Empty
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Good answer, and your approach to the solution is certainly comprehensive. In light of my understanding of how OP wants the criteria to be calculated, your approach would probably serve better than mine.

Comment: @Vegard, yes, I felt bad about wanting to write point 3 - though I also feel the point needed to be made - so thought I'd better do a comprehensive answer by way of recompense!